# How do I make re.finditer only return each line once

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am searching a text file that is a "phoneBook" for an assignment and am using regex finditer, but if a name has the letter a in it twice it prints that line twice which is what I am trying to avoid. Also is there a way to have it ignore case?

```py
def searchPhonebook(s): #This will search the phonebook(s) for the inputed data that is assigned to d
    print()
    d=input("Please enter the Name, Character, Phone Number, or a number: ") #Variable d which is the inputted data
    print()
    import re
    pattern = re.compile(d)
    for line in open("phone.txt"):
        for match in re.finditer(pattern,line):
            print(line)
```

So when I search 'a' it returns

```
Jack Hammer,277-4829
Jack Hammer,277-4829
Mike Rafone,345-3453
Earl Lee Riser,701-304-8293
```

So I would like it to return each one once, and also find capitalization of 'a', like Abby

Comment: use `re.search`, instead of `re.findall`.

Comment: This produces an error of 'object is not iterable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `findall()`. Just test whether the line matches the pattern:

```
for line in open("phone.txt"):
    if re.search(pattern, line):
        print(line)
```

Actually, I'm not sure why you're using `re` at all. Do your users really enter regular expression patterns? If they're just entering a plain string, use `if d in line:`

Comment: Thank you, like I said I am still a student, is there a way to make it ignore case so it would return a result like Abby?

Comment: `if d.lower() in line.lower():`

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot, I had tried it earlier but it hadn't worked (possibly as I had opened the file in a list), again thank you, I will mark correct once able